# Os.PathLike object - working with file sent via curl

Tags: python, subprocess, os.path, pdftotext

I'm wanting to curl POST a file to a flask app with this:

```
curl -X POST http://url_of_lambda_function.com -F 'file=@/path/to/file.pdf'
```

The flask app has the pdftotext executable running through a subprocess. Normally, this takes a couple of parameters as so...

```
result = subprocess.call([pdftotext, "-layout", file, "-"])
```

where pdftotext is the path to the executable, "-layout" is an option, file is the path to the pdf ('/path/to/file.pdf') and '-' is the output (in this case, dump it to screen).

**MY PROBLEM:**

In my flask app, I don't have a filepath for file as above. Instead, I'm handling the incoming file with this:

```
data = request.files['file']
file = data.read()
```

Data is a werkzeug fileobject and file is of class 'bytes'. Pdftotext accepts strings, bytes or os.Pathlike objects.

Feeding in file instead of '/path/to/file.pdf' gives an error:

```
ValueError: embedded null byte
```

Converting file to string and feeding in gives another error:

```
OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long: 'pdftotext'
```

I've tried wrapping this as a BytesIO object, StringIO object and IOTextWrapper but get caught with the error:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object
```

So I'm a bit stuck! This leaves me with only being able to give it a file path which I don't have when sending the file via curl!

**THOUGHTS:**

- I can download the file to temporary storage and pass in the path. This works but slows the function down so would rather avoid this if possible!
- Is there some other kind of wrapper I use which mimics the os.PathLike object or converts generates a temporary path??

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: A named temporary file is what you want.

Comment: Yes it is! Thanks @DanD. I'll update with an answer which shows this

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

Thanks to Dan D. in the comments to the question for suggesting to use NamedTemporaryFile().

```
tmpfile = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
tmpfile.write(file)
result = subprocess.call([pdftotext, "-layout", tmpfile.name, "-"])
```

Also got some use out of changing to subprocess.run to be able to save the output in a variable as follows:

```
result = subprocess.run(['pdftotext',tmpfile.name,'-'],stdout=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
text = result.stdout
```